# How do I read an RNA expression pattern?

Tags: gene-expression, rna-sequencing

When reading about diseases one can find links to proteins and their associated genes, an example of which is [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LMNA).

I'm wondering how to decode/read the following graph as a non-specialist in this area:

[image: RNA expression pattern]

What does it all mean?

Comment: This is not a particularly specialist graph, so like any other graph you (and we)  need to know what the axes are, what the colour-coding means, and what203411_s_at (i.e. the title info) means. Is there a figure legend? If so, please provide it in your question. I could explain what I think it is about, but you need to put some effort in yourself first.

Answer (score 1):

This image shows the expression of a gene (in your case Lamin A/C) in various tissues. A picture with a higher resultion for mouse looks like this (from [here](http://biogps.org/#goto=genereport&id=4000)): 
[image]

You can see the median expression (calculated from all samples) and can also see, in which tissues this gene is highly expressed and in which there is less or no expression.

This is important if you want to analyze the function of a gene. The tissue specific expression pattern can vary strongly between different tissues (as you can see in the figure) which can give information about the function of the gene. The same is true if you look on the time distribution of gene expression, you can identify genes which are important for different steps of differentiation.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. To make sure I understand, does the above graph indicate that lung tissue expresses that specific gene more (on average) than all other tissues? What do the numbers mean?

Comment: @UltimateHawk Yes, exactly. I am not sure about the number at the moment, but I guess they are relative to some normalisation.